# Encrypt in Android - Decrypt in Java

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to implement client-server architecture between Android device(client) and Java server (my laptop works as a normal server). I am trying to implement RSA algorithm to encrypt data sent by client and decrypt at the server. While sending I am first changing encrypted data to Base 64 string as :
Client:

```
    byte[] dataToEncrypt = temp.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); //temp is a String
    byte[] encryptedData = null;

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    //cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, serverPubKey);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
    String cipherStr = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I send `cipherStr`to server where I am using following code to decrypt it.

Server:

```
    byte[] decryptedData = null;
    System.out.println("Before Decryption:");
    System.out.println(tmp);

    byte [] byteArray = Base64.decode(tmp);

    try {
        privKey = pair.getPrivate();
        //  System.out.println("PRIVATE KEY IN FUNCTION"+privKey);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        // System.out.println(new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(byteArray);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Data: ");
        sentToDB = new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

However, at the server end, I am receiving BadPaddingException

Error:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)
    at sslservefr.simplesslserver$clientThread.run(simplesslserver.java:175)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at sslservefr.simplesslserver$clientThread.run(simplesslserver.java:198)
```

Can anyone please help? How do I go forward?
I read couple of questions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190369/decrypting-a-string-encrypted-on-an-android-device) .. but did not help.

EDIT : 
I found that Android is sending only half of the encrypted text

Android O/p:

```
11-22 13:44:21.530: W/Cipher String(2056): WRsALdJsVgIHqbg5x3ouYGsSwRKk5209lvyr4V8k1sj5IED9nSOoxTF3u9Ioz21l0oK5yOmtHeW4
11-22 13:44:21.530: W/Cipher String(2056): i1azUDYd+qD3Emtau8gEwJaYLOGfSgyhEtw4pbHSY2Nedp3iyqHahKyDcyxFSEWzSnOEMBRZInh8
11-22 13:44:21.530: W/Cipher String(2056): v0DyxAvRm8T8lxI5yVc=
```

What I receive in Java:

```
received: WRsALdJsVgIHqbg5x3ouYGsSwRKk5209lvyr4V8k1sj5IED9nSOoxTF3u9Ioz21l0oK5yOmtHeW4
```

Which is only the first line. I don't know why? If I am storing entire 'encryptedData' in String and sending it to the server.. why only first line is received in the Java server?

Please help me out !!! :(

EDIT2 : Because, Android splits the data, I did this on the server side:

```
           String l1 = br.readLine();
           String l2 = br.readLine();
           String l3 = br.readLine();
           tmp = l1+l2+l3;
```

Now I receive the data at Server exactly same as sent by Client, still I get the same error!!

Encrypted String sent from Client:

```
RpFC6Jq1bqH3IVjfQy91QlZ7C+btMkUQhZ5/HQWdC8LwRSaJlU63hEOHPzDltTpfV6u260MhhfwyNYuFbMS7WbFnpHLGMxR+WOPsZirG5Xr6QVm+b19bbZYgqDYxpaflvSRs2CnBQtKWFSsVg4nC9n6ICrhsQEhkA39P11IYt+U=
```

String received at Server:

```
RpFC6Jq1bqH3IVjfQy91QlZ7C+btMkUQhZ5/HQWdC8LwRSaJlU63hEOHPzDltTpfV6u260MhhfwyNYuFbMS7WbFnpHLGMxR+WOPsZirG5Xr6QVm+b19bbZYgqDYxpaflvSRs2CnBQtKWFSsVg4nC9n6ICrhsQEhkA39P11IYt+U=
```

Please help.

Comment: This looks like 2 separate exceptions concatenated together to me.

Comment: Yes! NumberFormatException is when I send data to Database using JDBC. Please ignore that part. Sorry about the confusion.
Any idea what could be the problem here otherwise? I tried sending encryptedData (without using Base64) and it failed as well. So the problem is not with Base 64 encoding-decoding (my initial guess).

Comment: use Base64.NO_WRAP instead of Base64.DEFAULT while encoding to avoid concatination done in edit 2

Comment: <SOLVED> So it turns out that it was failing because I was sending only 3 bit data. I appended a string to it, encrpyted - sent - recived - decrypted - remove extra string part, and used it. Not the best way, I know, but it served the purpose. Thanks for your help guys!:-)